# Preserve icon with rsync

Tags: macos, rsync, icons

I was under the impression from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453234/using-cp-and-preserving-the-attributes-of-a-directory-but-not-copying-any-of) among other research, that rsync was the command used to sync directories and any contents they have.

I have tried the following commands:

```
rsync -avzr ~/testing123 ~/Desktop/apartment
sudo rsync -avzr ~/testing123 ~/Desktop/apartment
```

Neither of them preserve the icon, they both produce the same result:

```
sent 544 bytes  received 92 bytes  1272.00 bytes/sec
total size is 6148  speedup is 9.67
building file list ... done
created directory /Users/null/Desktop/apartment
testing123/
testing123/.DS_Store
testing123/Icon\#015
testing123/info.txt

sent 566 bytes  received 92 bytes  1316.00 bytes/sec
total size is 6166  speedup is 9.37
```

They both sync the files correctly but do not preserve the icon from the original file or directory.  For directories, rather than preserving the icon on a folder, both commands create a '0 KB' file in the destination directory called 'Icon' with no extension. For files, it does nothing, no mystery 'Icon' file, and no actual icon.

Is it a matter of me using the wrong arguments? What is the problem here? Why won't `rsync` actually create the same icons on the destination files as on the source files?

Comment: Please make an effort to format your post properly.

Comment: My apologies, what did I not do that I should have done (besides a misspelling in the name that I did not notice until now)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to specify the `-E` option to `rsync`.

```
   -E, --extended-attributes
          Apple specific option  to  copy  extended  attributes,  resource
          forks,  and  ACLs.   Requires at least Mac OS X 10.4 or suitably
          patched rsync.
```

Icons are stored in HFS+ resource forks.

Comment: thanks! that was the answer! oh, this is not something I need to know in order to do this, but what actually was that file 'Icon' that was 0kb in a directory I was rsyncing?

Comment: You're welcome. See [here](http://superuser.com/a/298798/22317) for details.

Comment: Seems to me that this option is abbreviated "-X" in rsync 3.x. -E stands for "executability".