# What does a question mark after the file name mean using ls terminal command?

Tags: linux, macos, bash, terminal, finder

What does a question mark after the file name mean using ls terminal command?
*I am using a Mac running OS X Yosemite (v.10.10.5)*

When I do `ls` command at terminal, I get back a list of files (the same files I see when using finder) plus one additional file (named `Icons?`).

This file does not appear in Finder.

I removed it the normal way: `rm Icon?`

But what happened? How did the file get there? And why the `?` file extension?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Icon? file on OS X desktop](http://superuser.com/questions/298785/icon-file-on-os-x-desktop)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`?` is a single character wild card, so `Icon?` will match any filename that starts with `Icon` and contains only one more character such as `Icon2`.

Comment: True. But not the correct explanation in this case. See the duplicate answer.