# Icon files showing in OS X Finder

Tags: macos, finder

I have a bunch of Icon files showing in my Finder. I believe these are supposed to be hidden, I think it may be related to a terminal command I ran across my file system for another issue but now I have this side-effect.

How can I ensure all existing and future "Icon" files are hidden?

[image: Finder Icon Files]

Comment: This may provide some information http://superuser.com/questions/298785/icon-file-on-os-x-desktop

Comment: Just ran `find / -name Icon^M -exec chflags hidden {} \;` as root. Hopefully my filesystem is ok.

Answer (score 0):

You probably ran this command at some point to show all hidden files in Finder

```
 defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE; killall Finder
```

So to undo this, simply run this command

```
 defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE; killall Finder
```

Note that the restart of Finder using `killall` is required to affect this change since the value is only read during Finder's startup.

Comment: Thanks but that didn't fix the problem, I applied the command and Icon files still show after rebooting.